# Change text on div if class active

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Welcome. At the beginning I want tell us, that my english is poor :-)
So I have a problem with creating my website support on wordpress. My theme is fullpane where is section

```
<section id="homepage" class="clearfix section-post section-category-136 section-category-home-page default fullwidth post-16824 section type-section status-publish hentry ***active*** fullpage-active" data-anchor="homepage" style="height: 979px; padding: 0px 0px 70px; line-height: 894px;">
```

Like we can see name 'active' is generated automatically and I think that I can use it to my problem.

I want create some like index '1 for 5 section' on the right side window with fixed position and when I scroll to bottom number should change number '2 for 5 section'
So I create jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($( "#homepage" ).hasClass( "active" )){
            $("div#date").text("2 for 5");
        }
    });
</script>
```

And not working properly.
This page is located adress emotivo.pl/nowe

If I forgot tell us for something important tell me about it.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Modify your script to this:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var children = $("#superContainer").children(); 
    $(children).each(function(index,value) {
    if($(value).hasClass("active"))
        $("div#date").html(index+" of "+ children.length);
  });
});
</script>
```

This may not exactly work by copy pasting given your website is overriding scroll function, but the core logic is same.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it isn't work. Anything change. If I change 'active' to 'post-16824' start work.

Comment: It should look like                                                                                        <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($( "#homepage" ).hasClass( "active" )){
    $("div#date").html("2 for 5");
    }                                                                                  if($( "#welcome" ).hasClass( "active" )){
    $("div#date").html("3 for 5");
    } 
                                   
  });
</script>

Comment: There i have updated my answer. Check if this works.

Comment: I do not know what's going on. This script is paste to footer before body end tag, I think its ok yes? At the moment it's not working properly, when I touch scrollbar when website is loading then text in this div change but when I dont touch scrollbar nothing is changed. Even if it will change, that isnt change after scroll down, it stay 0 of 5. Maybe I will give you more information about this page? J dont know